# PSTricks: ugly pie chart

Tags: pstricks, pstricks-add

I use PSTricks to draw a pie chart but when I do

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[pdf]{pstricks}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\begin{document}
\titlepage
\begin{pspicture}(-5,-5)(5,5)
\psChart[chartColor=color]{0.722278,0.0893228,0.0788649}{}{0.5}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

the result is ugly:

[image: Here is the ugly pie chart i get]

I mean by that if you zoom in the center of the pie, you can see that the pieces are overlapping. How can I correct that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use

```
\psChart[chartColor=color,linestyle=none]{0.722278,0.0893228,0.0788649}{}{0.5}
```