# PSTricks: Problem with pie chart coloring

Tags: pstricks-add

This is more or less a follow-up question to the question [PSTricks: ugly pie chart](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/140613/15874) by [PinkFloyd](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/38928/pinkfloyd).

Consider the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
 \psset{
   unit = 2.9,
   nodesepA = 5pt,
   nodesepB = -10pt
 }
  \begin{pspicture}(-1.0,-1.37)(1.5,1.4)
    \psChart[
      userColor = {red!60,green!60,blue!60},
      chartNodeO = 1.25,
      shadow = true,
      shadowsize = 5pt,
      linestyle = none
    ]{54, 594, 890}{}{1}
    \rput(psChartI1){\SI{54}{\tonne}}
    \ncline{psChartO1}{psChart1}
    \nput{0}{psChartO1}{F{\o}r}
    \rput(psChartI2){\SI{594}{\tonne}}
    \ncline{psChartO2}{psChart2}
    \nput{90}{psChartO2}{Under}
    \rput(psChartI3){\SI{890}{\tonne}}
    \ncline{psChartO3}{psChart3}
    \nput{-90}{psChartO3}{Efter}
  \end{pspicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

When I correct the overlapping of the pie charts by invoking `linestyle=none`, togethter with the `shadow=true` option, there is a white border between the piechart and its shadow, I would like to get rit of. How do I do this?

Comment: set `linewidth=0`.

Comment: Wait for a couple of seconds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting `linewidth=0` is enough. `linestyle=none` is not necessary.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\usepackage{siunitx}

 \psset
{
    unit = 2.9,
    nodesepA = 5pt,
    nodesepB = -10pt,
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{pspicture}(-1.0,-1.37)(1.5,1.4)
    \psChart
    [
      userColor = {red!60,green!60,blue!60},
      chartNodeO = 1.25,
      shadow = true,
      linewidth=0,
      shadowsize = 5pt,
    ]{54, 594, 890}{}{1}
    \rput(psChartI1){\SI{54}{\tonne}}
    \ncline{psChartO1}{psChart1}
    \nput{0}{psChartO1}{F{\o}r}
    \rput(psChartI2){\SI{594}{\tonne}}
    \ncline{psChartO2}{psChart2}
    \nput{90}{psChartO2}{Under}
    \rput(psChartI3){\SI{890}{\tonne}}
    \ncline{psChartO3}{psChart3}
    \nput{-90}{psChartO3}{Efter}
    \end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]